# Writeable Nested Serializer, overriding .create() - Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have AttendanceSlot model which has a foreign key to Course model, I want my endpoint to return the actual course code, not just the primary key. But I'm getting the below error when I try to override the .create(). please, I don't know where i'm getting it wrong.

```
TypeError at /attendance/attendance-slot/
Field 'id' expected a number but got OrderedDict([('course_code', 'COM411')]).
```

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_code = models.CharField(_("Course Code"), max_length=50)
    course_title = models.CharField(_("Course Title"), max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.course_code) 

class AttendanceSlot(models.Model):
    department_id = models.ForeignKey("students.Department", verbose_name=_("department id"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_id = models.ForeignKey("students.Course", verbose_name=_("course id"), related_name= 'course', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lecturer_id = models.ForeignKey("lecturers.Lecturer", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(_("attendance date"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(_("start time"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
  

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.course_id.course_code)
```

below is my serializers.py

```
class CourseMini(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['id','course_code']

class AttendanceSlotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    course_id = CourseMini()

    class Meta:
        model = AttendanceSlot
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        course = Course.objects.get(pk = validated_data.pop('course_id'))
        instance = AttendanceSlot.objects.create(**validated_data)
        instance.course_id = course
        instance.save()
        return instance
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(AttendanceSlotSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        return representation
```

views.py

```
class AttendanceSlotView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = AttendanceSlot.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AttendanceSlotSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(lecturer_id=self.request.user.lecturer)
        return super().perform_create(serializer)
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with passing the id of the course instead of the whole object to returning instance?

Comment: l tried ```course = Course.objects.get(pk = validated_data.pop('course_id').get('id'))```, didn't  work